# I want to read this json valus ( channelname& channelno only ) in delphi 11.3

Tags: delphi

```json
[
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS DOLBY+",
    "channelno": "DL"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS ITALY",
    "channelno": "IT"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS PREM1",
    "channelno": "P1"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS PREM2",
    "channelno": "P2"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS PREM3",
    "channelno": "P3"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS SSC1",
    "channelno": "S1"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS SSCXTRA",
    "channelno": "SX"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS VARIETY",
    "channelno": "GV"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 1",
    "channelno": "1"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 2",
    "channelno": "2"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 3",
    "channelno": "3"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 4",
    "channelno": "4"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 5",
    "channelno": "5"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 6",
    "channelno": "6"
  },
  {
    "channelname": "GOSAT PLUS 7",
    "channelno": "7"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello عبد الرؤوف جلابي ,

```
uses
    System.JSON
...
procedure showData(s: String);
var
  JArr   : TJSONArray;
  JVal, JItem : TJSONValue;
begin
  JArr    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s),0) as TJSONArray;
  for JVal in JArr do
  begin
    for JItem in TJSONArray(JVal) do
      showmessage(Format('%s : %s',[TJSONPair(JItem).JsonString.Value, TJSONPair(JItem).JsonValue.Value]));
   end;
end;
```

where `TJSONPair(JItem).JsonString.Value` is your attribute/element name and `TJSONPair(JItem).JsonValue.Value` is value of the element

Comment: (TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s),0) as 

s variable is my json string or what

Comment: procedure parameter s is your string